# Exponentiating similar Laplacians

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, graph-theory, matrix-exponential, graph-laplacian

Let $L_c$ be the $n\times n$ Laplacian matrix of the complete graph, and $L$ be the $n\times n$ Laplacian of any simple, connected graph possessing a vertex $k$ of maximum degree $d_k=n-1$. Clearly, there is a column of $L$ that looks like the corresponding column of $L_c$.

Now, consider the exponential matrices $e^{-itL_c}$ and $e^{-itL}$, where $t>0$ is a real parameter. Is the equality of the same columns preserved? I've been playing around with this in Mathematica and haven't come up with a counterexample.

**Edit.** Here are a few examples. For the star graph we obtain with $n=5$ the following matrix: $$\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
 \frac{1}{5} \left(1+4 e^5\right) & \frac{1}{5} \left(1-e^5\right) & \frac{1}{5} \left(1-e^5\right) & \frac{1}{5} \left(1-e^5\right) & \frac{1}{5} \left(1-e^5\right) \\
 \frac{1}{5} \left(1-e^5\right) & \frac{1}{20} \left(4+15 e+e^5\right) & \frac{1}{20} \left(4-5 e+e^5\right) & \frac{1}{20} \left(4-5 e+e^5\right) & \frac{1}{20} \left(4-5 e+e^5\right) \\
 \frac{1}{5} \left(1-e^5\right) & \frac{1}{20} \left(4-5 e+e^5\right) & \frac{1}{20} \left(4+15 e+e^5\right) & \frac{1}{20} \left(4-5 e+e^5\right) & \frac{1}{20} \left(4-5 e+e^5\right) \\
 \frac{1}{5} \left(1-e^5\right) & \frac{1}{20} \left(4-5 e+e^5\right) & \frac{1}{20} \left(4-5 e+e^5\right) & \frac{1}{20} \left(4+15 e+e^5\right) & \frac{1}{20} \left(4-5 e+e^5\right) \\
 \frac{1}{5} \left(1-e^5\right) & \frac{1}{20} \left(4-5 e+e^5\right) & \frac{1}{20} \left(4-5 e+e^5\right) & \frac{1}{20} \left(4-5 e+e^5\right) & \frac{1}{20} \left(4+15 e+e^5\right) \\
\end{array}
\right)$$ where clearly the first column is the same as the first column of the exponential of $L_c$, given by $$\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
 \frac{1}{5} \left(1+4 e^5\right) & \frac{1}{5} \left(1-e^5\right) & \frac{1}{5} \left(1-e^5\right) & \frac{1}{5} \left(1-e^5\right) & \frac{1}{5} \left(1-e^5\right) \\
 \frac{1}{5} \left(1-e^5\right) & \frac{1}{5} \left(1+4 e^5\right) & \frac{1}{5} \left(1-e^5\right) & \frac{1}{5} \left(1-e^5\right) & \frac{1}{5} \left(1-e^5\right) \\
 \frac{1}{5} \left(1-e^5\right) & \frac{1}{5} \left(1-e^5\right) & \frac{1}{5} \left(1+4 e^5\right) & \frac{1}{5} \left(1-e^5\right) & \frac{1}{5} \left(1-e^5\right) \\
 \frac{1}{5} \left(1-e^5\right) & \frac{1}{5} \left(1-e^5\right) & \frac{1}{5} \left(1-e^5\right) & \frac{1}{5} \left(1+4 e^5\right) & \frac{1}{5} \left(1-e^5\right) \\
 \frac{1}{5} \left(1-e^5\right) & \frac{1}{5} \left(1-e^5\right) & \frac{1}{5} \left(1-e^5\right) & \frac{1}{5} \left(1-e^5\right) & \frac{1}{5} \left(1+4 e^5\right) \\
\end{array}
\right).$$ It's easy enough to see that this works for a generic $n$, as the dependance of the coefficients on $n$ is straightforward. A simpler example is the path graph on three vertices, which gives $$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 \frac{1}{6} \left(2+3 e+e^3\right) & \frac{1}{3} \left(1-e^3\right) & \frac{1}{6} \left(2-3 e+e^3\right) \\
 \frac{1}{3} \left(1-e^3\right) & \frac{1}{3} \left(1+2 e^3\right) & \frac{1}{3} \left(1-e^3\right) \\
 \frac{1}{6} \left(2-3 e+e^3\right) & \frac{1}{3} \left(1-e^3\right) & \frac{1}{6} \left(2+3 e+e^3\right) \\
\end{array}
\right)$$ to be compared with the $3\times 3$ $e^{L_c}$ matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so after fiddling around with it for a bit, I got a proof.
It can perhaps be made a little bit shorter.
Also, everything should go through with the $-it$ term, but I didn't include this in the proof.

We begin with a lemma which provides a necessary condition on the first column of $A$ in $B$.

**Lemma**
Let $A$ and $B$ be symmetric matrices with the same first column, denoted $v = A e_1 = B e_1$.
If $A v = B v = \alpha v$ for some $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$, then $\exp(A)$ and $\exp(B)$ have the same first column.

**Proof**
Recall that the matrix exponential is defined as
$$\exp (A) = I + A + \frac{1}{2} A^2 + \frac{1}{6} A^3 + \dots = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!} A^k$$
Using this, we have that the first column of $\exp(A)$ is given by
$$ 
\exp (A) e_1
= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!} A^k e_1
= I e_1 + \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k!} A^k e_1
= e_1 + \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k!} A^{k-1} v .$$
The same argument may be used to obtain the first column of $\exp(B)$.
Note that the first term $e_1$ is independent of the matrix being exponentiated.
Thus, by canceling this common term, we have that the first column of $\exp(A)$ is equal to the first column of $\exp(B)$ if and only if
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k!} A^{k-1} v = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k!} B^{k-1} v
$$
We now show that the corresponding terms in both series are equal by induction on $k$.
The base case of $k=1$ follows as
$$A^{k-1} v = A^{0} v = I v = B^{0} v = B^{k-1} v.$$
Suppose that for each $k \leq r$, $A^{k-1} v = B^{k-1} v$.
Then for $k=r+1$ with $r \geq 1$,
\begin{align}
A^{(r+1)-1} v &= A^{r} v \\
&= A^{r-1} (A  v) \\
&= A^{r-1} (\alpha v) &\text{(By assumption, $Av = \alpha v$)}\\
&= \alpha (A^{r-1} v) \\
&= \alpha (B^{r-1} v) &\text{(inductive hypothesis)}\\
&= B^{r-1} (\alpha v) \\
&= B^{r-1} B v &\text{(By assumption, $Bv = \alpha v$)}\\
&= B^r v\\
&= B^{(r+1)-1} v
\end{align}
Thus, we have shown that all terms in the series are equal, so that the first columns of $\exp(A)$ and $\exp(B)$ are equal. $\square$

The last thing we need is the following claim, which makes use of Laplacian matrices. I'll leave it as an exercise to prove since it's very similar to the fact that the all ones vector $\mathbf{1}$ is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $0$.

**Claim** If $L$ is a Laplacian matrix whose first row/column is $v = \begin{pmatrix} n-1, & -1, & -1, & \dots, & -1 \end{pmatrix}$, then $L v = n \cdot v$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Chris. I modified the question to be more specific: I am comparing the exponentials $\exp(-itL)$ and $\exp(-itL_c)$. At least in this case, the path graph on three vertices isn't a counterexample: the column corresponding to the second vertix is actually the same as the complete graph even when passing to the exponentials. Also, the star graphs I have checked work fine. Same for the wheel graphs, and a couple others. I am doing all this for relatively low dimensions, however, but it seems to be easily generalizable.

Comment: Also, to be as clear as possible, I am only considering the vertex with maximum degree. It doesn't matter what everything else looks like, as long as there is one such vertex in the graph.

Comment: For example, sticking to the original calculations, without the factor $-it$ which is pretty much irrelevant, $e^L$ for the path graph has the column $$(\frac{1}{3}(1-e^3),\frac{1}{3}(1+2e^3),\frac{1}{3}(1-e^3))^t,$$ identical to the second column of $L_c$.

Comment: Oh, hmmm...all my intuition is for real vector spaces so I'm not what (if anything) changes when we add the $-i t$ factor. Before writing my answer, I did code up the star graph to numerically check things so I think that counterexample is correct (of course, without the $-it$ factor). I'll see if I can reproduce the code here. In the mean time, here's a question: what is your definition of matrix exponential? Is it what I gave above or are you applying the exponent to the individual entries?

Comment: I confirm I am using the usual definition of matrix exponentiation as a power series. Also, I have checked the star graph again, and I found no counterexample. The $\LaTeX$ code exceeds the character limitation here, so I will put a few examples in the main post.

Comment: I just typed up some `Julia` code again and found that you're right! I was wrong about the star graph being a counterexample - it must have been my fat fingers earlier :) And I ran this on some random examples and it works, even when the edge weights on vertices $2,3 \dots n$ are randomly chosen in [0,1]. This is pretty surprising to me! Let me play around with it more on Monday and see if I can get a proof.

Comment: Hmmm...playing around with some `Julia` code, I see that this relation doesn't hold for general positive semidefinite matrices $A$ and $B$. That is, if $A$ and $B$ are positive semidefinite with the same first row/column, then it's not necessary true that $\exp(A)$ and $\exp(B)$ share the same first row and column. Which matches my intuition above. Further restricting that $A \preceq B$ is psd ordering doesn't help either. So it's probably got something to do with the Laplacian structure...

Comment: This is great. I was thinking to proceed along the same line with a proof by induction from the relationship $A^ke_1=B^ke_1$ but I was missing the key insight that $$L(n-1,-1,...,-1)=n(n-1,-1,...,-1),$$ so thank you very much for this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110511/discussion-between-chris-harshaw-and-totalnoob).